# Notification: BTPLN vs TPLNR

Tags: abap, netweaver

I have this data type to hold the information to create a notification.

```
DATA: LS_NOTIFHEADER LIKE BAPI2080_NOTHDRI.
```

I want to create a notification with a functional location and an affected functional location. I know I can add the functional location with

```
LS_NOTIFHEADER-TPLNR = '1010-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'.
```

Is there also a field to add the affected functional location (BTPLN)?

This is the code I use to create the notification.

```
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE'
    EXPORTING
      NOTIF_TYPE         = 'M1' 
      NOTIFHEADER        = LS_NOTIFHEADER
    IMPORTING
      NOTIFHEADER_EXPORT = LS_NOTIF
    TABLES
      RETURN             = LT_RETURN.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to specify affected location in BAPI.

But user-exit `EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017` (enhancement QQMA0025) may be helpful for you. It is called by BAPI and there you can modify BTPLN.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!